# UITableViewCell frame height is always 44px

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, heightforrowatindexpath

I am setting the height of cell using heightForRowAtIndexPath: method returning 100.
But in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, the cell's frame height is always 44px.

Following is my code.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}

- (int) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%f %f", cell.frame.size.height, cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
    return  cell;
}
```

The NSLog statement prints "44px 44px".

I am able to get the correct height using this statement

```
CGFloat height = [tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Do you have a prototype cell in Interface Builder with an id of "Cell" and a height of 44?

Comment: The default UITableViewCell is 44. Height of 100px is applied during the drawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Delegate Method will not be called while allocating the cell. `initWithStyle` allways returns cells with height of 44 unless you overwrite it in a subclass.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. will have to overwrite it in subclass then.

Comment: @Dhawal actualy you dont really need to, the height will be set correct befor the cell is Displayed (if you have set the delegate).

Comment: i can confirm that setting the height is required in the initWithStyle method even with the correct delegate methods.

Comment: what do u mean initWithStyle? I am giving height for row UITableViewAutomaticDimension and I see the frame is larger than 44 but in init method the size is 44